# How to display the number of lines of comments as percentage?

Tags: sonarqube, comments

How can I configure SonarQube to display the comment percentage of my code?

I could not find the solution in the [official documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions) about metrics in SonarQube.

Currently my Measures page looks like this:

[image: Size measures]

How I can add a measure for count the comments % ?

Comment: This metrics should be displayed on Size measures page as in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4xQV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In SonarQube 6.6 (for example), there is a measure called `Comments (%)`. It is also mentioned in [the official documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions#MetricDefinitions-Documentation):

> Comments (%)
>
> Density of comment lines = Comment
> lines / (Lines of code + Comment lines) * 100

You can for example see this measures in your project's "Measures" tab, when selecting [the domain "size"](https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures/domain/Size?id=net.java.openjdk%3Ajdk9), or, in later SonarQube versions, you can even see a [line chart](https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures/metric/comment_lines_density/list?id=net.java.openjdk%3Ajdk9) for this measure. (the links show the measure for JDK9 on sonarcloud.io)

Comment: But how to enable this metric to display? :) By default, this metric is not displayed. Should I somehow configure the SonarQube to display this metric or should it be displayed by default? I'm using SonarQube version 6.4

Comment: @BlackBars I'm sorry, but I do not understand. This measure *is* displayed. (in the "Measures" tab, when selecting "size") Do you want it to be displayed elsewhere?

Comment: When I perform a code checking, SonarQube does not display information about comment percentage of my code. I would like to know what I need to do, so that SonarQube began to showing this metric

Answer (score 0):

You would find the Comments percentage as below
1.Click on the Project for which you want to see the Comments percentage.
2.You would see the menus "OverView " "Issues" "Measures"
3.Click on "Measures" link
4.Under project review various links
5. Click on menu "Size " , you would see Comment Lines and Comments (%)